# IsNot Operator Mistake VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Quick Q:

```
Sub Ex()
Worksheets("ABC").Activate
If Range("B10").Text IsNot "USA" Then
Range("B11").Value = "Domestic"
Else
End If
End Sub
```

I am new to VBA, and have not picked up what I have done wrong here. 
I am trying to set up values in B11 such that if B10 is set to anything else other than "USA" then the value in must be "Domestic".

**Bonus Question:** Ideally I would like to be able to create a list in B11 if I select USA. How can I do this with data validation?

Comment: As mentioned by John, `IsNot` is an operator that is not available in VBA, only in VB.NET. BTW, `IsNot` operate on Object references, I'm not sure it would work on basic type `String`.

Comment: For the "Bonus Question":  You can either use [Range.Validation.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/validation-add-method-excel) or [Create conditional drop-down lists](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2009/11/24/create-conditional-drop-down-lists/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IsNot` is a VB.Net rather than a VBA operator. Instead, use `<>` (which corresponds to `!=` in many other languages):

```
Sub Ex()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("ABC")
    If ws.Range("B10").Text <> "USA" Then
        ws.Range("B11").Value = "Domestic"
    End If
End Sub
```

I made a couple of other changes: I introduced a worksheet variable and used it to qualify the `Range()` (rather than relying on activation) and I dropped the spurious `Else`.

Comment: Why did you introduce the worksheet variable rather than activation?

Comment: Failing to qualify ranges by worksheet is a bad habit (which I am often guilty of) that leads to bugs sooner or later. Furthermore, things like `select` and `activate` are seldom needed in VBA. Better to directly use the Excel Object Model rather than mimicking user actions. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248).

Comment: Hi @user9078057, [here are some examples of why you shouldn't use `.select` or `.activate`](https://www.businessprogrammer.com/power-excel-vba-secret-avoid-using-select/)

Comment: You might also want to avoid `Text` - that is what is displayed in the cell rather than the value it contains.  Usually the same, but can be `#####` (for dates with a small column width), or if cell has custom format to display something different.